# how to do undo in android

Tags: android

```
 onTouch(MotionEvent event){
 int x = (int) event.getX();
 int y = (int) event.getY();

 if(event.getAction==MotionEvent.DOWN){
       temp_point = new ArrayList<Point>();
       temp_point.add(new Point(x,y);
 }else if(event.getAction==MotionEvent.MOVE){
       if(temp_point!=null)
          temp_point.add(new Point(x,y);
 }else if(event.getAction==MotionEvent.UP){
       mainPoint.add(temp_point);
       temp_point = null;
 }
 return true;
```

}

I am doing paint using canvas. I'm able to erase the paint, but I'm not able to undo the last did paint.

Comment: Tried to undo _what_?

Comment: What are you trying to do... please describe ur problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) if you're interested in implementing undo/redo in a situation like this.

It has nothing to do with Android per-se. You're on your own to implement the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can stave your paint object in one   array like paint[] .
i try roughly figure-out it .

Paint [] paint= new Paint[counter]  //counter is the number of object that you want .

the object of array will create new when you want to apply new paint object to canvas and paralleled your counter will increment ..

when you **undo** then your counter will decrements so that you can get previous one object of paint and you can apply to canvas its means its undo you canvas ..